# Why would an email sent from C# be received by the destination email but not by the CC?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I am using C#. I have a method in which the SMTP client is configured and an email is sent:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("myEmail@myDomain.com", "otherEmail@google.com");

mail.CC.Add("otherEmailInMyDomain@myDomain.com");

mail.Subject = "Normal Subject";
mailMessage.Body = "Normal Body";
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Port = 587;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = credentials;
client.Host = "smtp.office365.com";
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

The email is being received by the **otherEmail@google.com** (to which it is being sent directly), but is not being received by the **otherEmailInMyDomain@myDomain.com**.

**This error only happens in the server, whenever i try this code in my machine, it works perfectly.**

Comment: Does the sender receive a bounce message? The recipient server may not trust mail from the IP address it is coming from. It doesn't seem like a code issue.

Comment: Not to mention Microsoft doesn't recommend you use this library anymore.